# Create a Text File in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a string

```
a = """
---
title: Just a test
author: Me
date: 2022-01-03
---

# Test Header 
Some text.
"""
```

from which I want to create a file `foobar.jmd`. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fname = "foobar.jmd"
dirpath = "/tmp"
fpath = joinpath(dirpath, fname)

open(fpath, "w") do file
    write(file, a)
end
```

More examples e.g. here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Working_with_text_files

Comment: `write(fpath, a)` is a nice and equivalent shorthand.